How to numerically compute the gap function $ |\Delta| $ as a function of energy from this self-consistent equation?
I am working on calculating the gap function $ |\Delta| $ as a function of energy in a superconductor. The self-consistent equation I am using is:
$
\frac{1}{V} = \frac{1}{2D} \int_{-D}^{+D} \left[ \beta_1 \tanh \left( \frac{Y_1}{2T} \right) + \beta_2 \tanh \left( \frac{Y_2}{2T} \right) \right] dx,
$
where:
$
\beta_1 = \frac{Y_1^2 - \bar{x}^2}{2Y_1(Y_1^2 - Y_2^2)}, \quad \beta_2 = \frac{Y_2^2 - \bar{x}^2}{2Y_2(Y_1^2 - Y_2^2)},
$
and:
$
Y_{1,2}^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left[x_1^2 + \bar{\bar{x}}_1^2 + |\Delta|^2 \pm \sqrt{(x_1^2 + \bar{\bar{x}}_1^2 + |\Delta|^2)^2 - 4(x_1^2 \bar{x}_1^2 + |\Delta|^2 \bar{\bar{x}}_1^2)} \right].
$
Here, $ x_1, \bar{x}_1, \bar{\bar{x}}_1, \bar{x}$, and $ |\Delta| $ are functions of $x $, and $ V $ is the interaction strength. The energy range is $ -D \leq x \leq D $, and $ T $ is the temperature.
$x_1 = x - \mu$
$\bar{x_1} = x_1 + U$
$\bar{\bar{x_1}} = x_1 + (1 - \rho) U$
My goal is to numerically compute $ |\Delta| $ as a function of $ x $ by solving this equation self-consistently. Could someone provide guidance or suggestions on:

A reliable numerical method to solve this integral equation for $ |\Delta| $.
How to ensure numerical stability in the presence of the square root and the $ \tanh $ terms.
Any simplifications or approximations that might help in implementing this calculation.


This is not a full answer. I am just trying to help a little. Your notation is very annoying to work with. The only appearance of $\Delta$ comes in the form of $|\Delta|^2$, so you actually lose nothing by defining $\Delta$ as the unique positive real value that it can be.
Let $y=x-\mu,\ z=y+U,\ w=y+(1-\rho)U$ and
$$Y^2_\pm=\frac12\left[y^2+w^2+\Delta^2\pm\sqrt{(y^2+w^2+\Delta^2)^2-4(y^2z^2+w^2\Delta^2)}\,\right]$$
We will need a simplification of the square root, and so we should study it separately.
$$(y^2+w^2+\Delta^2)^2-4(y^2z^2+w^2\Delta^2)=(y^2-w^2+\Delta^2)^2-4y^2(z^2-w^2)$$
The parametrisation strongly hints that $0\leqslant\rho\leqslant1$ and taking $U\geqslant0$, means that $y\leqslant w\leqslant z$, so that if we also assume that $y^2+\Delta^2\leqslant w^2$, then the inside of the square root becomes $(w^2-y^2-\Delta^2)^2-4y^2\rho U(2y+2U-\rho U)$
and you should check whether the first term is guaranteed to be bigger in magnitude than what is subtracted off.
Now, the denominator of the $\beta$ terms have $Y^2_+-Y^2_-$, which is just twice the square root. Needless to say, my own notation would be $\beta_\pm$ rather than your 1 and 2.
I think you have a typo; $\Delta$ should not depend upon $x$ if your problem is to make sense.

Now, for the computation, I can only guess. It is clear that in a superconductor, $T$ is tiny. This means that we should expect the $\tanh$ terms to saturate. It probably would make sense to break the integral into 3 parts, two parts for when the $\tanh$ terms are saturated in each side, and the middle part when it is almost linear and thus do the $\dfrac{\tanh x}x$ expansion.
If you expect the gap $\Delta$ to be small compared to all other terms, then you should start with $\Delta=0$ and see which $V$ you obtain. Then you slowly increase $\Delta$ until you overshoot, and then take smaller steps backwards. At least, with all the analytical manipulations above, no part of these computations should collide with a singularity, especially due to the $\frac{\tanh x}x$ expansion. That means that the integrals should numerically converge and not give trouble.

Thanks.
You are correct on both points: the notation is annoying, and I must choose a different one. Furthermore, delta must be constant (not dependent on x) due to the author's assumption of a flat density of states
